What does _weakrefset calls in python stack trace mean?
I captured stack traces of a running Python process and noticed many _weakrefset.py calls at the end of the trace.
These _remove calls are never explicitly called in the code.
Does anyone know what this is about?
Samples:
/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dataclasses.py, line 1284, in asdict return _asdict_inner(obj, dict_factory)

File: /usr/local/lib/python3.11/dataclasses.py, line 1291, in _asdict_inner value = _asdict_inner(getattr(obj, f.name), dict_factory)

File: /usr/local/lib/python3.11/dataclasses.py, line 1290, in _asdict_inner for f in fields(obj):

File: /usr/local/lib/python3.11/dataclasses.py, line 1248, in fields return tuple(f for f in fields.values() if f._field_type is _FIELD)

File: /usr/local/lib/python3.11/_weakrefset.py, line 39, in _remove def _remove(item, selfref=ref(self))

File: /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ddtrace/internal/compat.py, line 163, in func_wrapper result = await coro(*args, **kwargs)

File: /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/integrity_rules_engine/core/rule_evaluator.py, line 57, in evaluate_rules rule_results_and_exceptions = await asyncio.gather(

File: /usr/local/lib/python3.11/asyncio/tasks.py, line 817, in gather fut = _ensure_future(arg, loop=loop)

File: /usr/local/lib/python3.11/asyncio/tasks.py, line 670, in _ensure_future return loop.create_task(coro_or_future)

File: /usr/local/lib/python3.11/_weakrefset.py, line 39, in _remove def _remove(item, selfref=ref(self)


I suspect it's related to garbage collection. It's removing weak references that refer to objects that have been reclaimed.

This module is used to manage weak references in Python
A weak reference allows an object to be referenced without preventing it from being garbage collected. The _remove function mentioned in the trace is part of Python's weak reference handling mechanism, which removes an item from a weak reference set when it's no longer needed.
In your second example, it seems that the asynchronous task management (asyncio.gather, create_task) triggered some garbage collection or cleanup involving weak references, possibly when a coroutine finished executing.
Same thing with the first one; the cleanup process interacted with weak references to ensure objects are correctly removed without being prematurely deleted.
